# Reputation by graph bug

Tags: support

On the reputation page, if you choose to view the reputation by graph, two graphs show up. Beneath the lower one it says:

> select an area by dragging across the lower chart

I can't seem to understand what to do here. I click and drag, I drag parts of the higher graph to the lower one, and all kinds of clicking and dragging. Nothing happens. What does it want me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, thanks to @Matt Эллен's comment. In Chrome, if you're zoomed in (by pressing 'Control' & '+') you can't highlight any part of the graph. On Firefox you can. So I un-zoomed and all was good.

Answer (score 3):

What it means is that you should hold the left mouse button down while the mouse pointer is  on the lower graph and drag along the graph to select which part of your reputation you wish to see. See the below image

[image: high lighting where to drag the selection on the lower graph]

The area I have highlighted in red is the one I selected by dragging.

Comment: Sounds simple enough. Too bad it doesn't work for me. I can click anywhere and hold as long as I want (while dragging of course) and nothing gets selected. The only thing that happens is the mouse changes from an arrow to a cursor, but nothing gets highlighted.

Comment: @Mark - interesting. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. I'll try a different one. By the way, what's supposed to happen if you highlight a section?